# My contract is failing ether transactions but receiving ERC20 tokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

Im trying to pay a contract address through metamask and have it call a buyTokens function but the transactions keep failing. The contract has enough tokens balance because because I sent the ERC20 tokens successfully to the contract address through metamask. It is only when I send ether to the contract address that it fails. I tried with the default gas limmit and tried it with gas set to 200000 in metamask. Please help me.

Im running on genache, local host

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./Token.sol";

// rate is 1 token = 0.01 ether

contract Crowdsale {

    constructor() public {
        rate = 100;
        on = true;
    }

    Token public token;
    address payable wallet;
    uint256 public rate;
    bool on;

    event TokenPurchase(address recipient, uint256 numPaid, uint256 numTokensPurchased);

    function buyTokens() public payable {
        
        require(msg.value > 0 && on == true);
        uint256 tokenAmount = _getTokenAmount(msg.value);
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= tokenAmount);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
        emit TokenPurchase( msg.sender, msg.value, tokenAmount);

    }
    
    function () external payable{
        buyTokens();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try call `buyTokens` directly. The **fallback** function can only rely on 2300 gas being available, which is not enough to call `buyTokens`.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function

Comment: thats not it. I have tried every function and they all fail. its something to do with the token contract not instantiating in the Crowdsale contract. I added 'code'    function test() public view returns(uint){
        balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }'code' but that throws an error but when I do balanceOf() from the token contract in truffle it works

Comment: Where do you init the `token` with an address?

```lang-js
Token public token;
```